# Unable to get the onChange Event to trigger using ReactJs and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have developed react within other frameworks such as Django and Ruby on Rails, and recently have tried to develop using Node.js. However, I cannot get the onChange event in an input box to trigger, below is the code I am using.

server.js

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

let routes = require('./routes/index');

app.use('/',routes);
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jsx');
app.engine('jsx', require('express-react-views').createEngine());

app.use("/public/styles", express.static(__dirname + '/public/styles'));
app.use("/public/js", express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'));
app.use("/public/fonts", express.static(__dirname + '/public/fonts'));
app.use("/public/font", express.static(__dirname + '/public/font'));


let server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () =>{
   console.log("App is running.");
});
```

routes/index.js

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
   res.render('index',{});
})

module.exports = router;
```

views/index.jsx

```
let React = require('react');
let ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
let DefaultLayout = require('./layout/master').default
export default class Landing extends React.Component {
      render() {
         return (
            <div>
                    <input type="text" onChange={() => {console.log("HERE")}} />
                    <br />

            </div>
            );
      }
}
```

I have tried changing my code from ES6 to ES5 syntax and yet I am still not getting the words to appear I know that I should be expecting the "HERE" to come out in the terminal display, but I can't get it to appear.

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsbin.com/jekuqerowu/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Ok I wonder then if it is the version of stuff I am using. What version nodejs is that?

Comment: "HERE" will appear in the browser console, but not in terminal according to your code.

Comment: If I put a HERE in the render method it appears in the terminal when running it as node.js

Comment: you need to pass the data from your client-side (react js) back to your server-side (node js). right now, it's not doing that. in your node router.get method, you're only displaying the index file template.

Comment: Let me restate, I put a "HERE" before the render method it prints; however, when I put it in the onChange() it doesn't work. It feels like to me the onChange is never getting fired, but you are saying I should make a route to post to in routes.js file and then make an ajax call to that?

Comment: You understand that React runs in the browser, right? It's a client-side framework. A ReactJS event should never by itself cause terminal output from the server, without issuing another HTTP request to the nodejs server.

Comment: I believe Node.js is compiling it from ES6 syntax into ES5 syntax; and then possibly server side rendering it. But if you don' believe me I can upload a picture to Imgur

Comment: I see what's happening, but I still don't understand why you expect the _client-side_ button to cause an event to happen server side, when there's no code to actually _do_ that. Server rendering just means rendering HTML (hence why you see the log if it's in `render()`).